# pointer to pointer to constant

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a function `const void* getData()` which returns a pointer to constant data `const void*`
I need to write a wrapper to this function that gets an (output) argument in which it should return the above pointer.

```
void wrapGetData([type] ppData) {
*ppData = getData();
}
```

What should be the `[type]`? 
void ** is not sutable,since getData() returns pointer to the const

Answer (score 5):

If `getData()` returns `void const *`, then `[type]` should be `void const * &`:

```
void wrapGetData(void const * & ppData) 
{
    ppData = getData();
}
```

Note that `&` is needed, as `ppData` is output parameter.

You can call this function as:

```
void const * output;

wrapGetData(output);
```

This is a bit different from the other solution in which you have to call the function as:

```
wrapGetData(&output); //if [type] = const void **
```

Note that `const void*` and `void const*` are same thing. So don't confuse with the syntax.

---

This is a bit different from the other solution in which you have to call the function as:

```
wrapGetData(&output); //if [type] = const void **
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`const void**`:

```
const void *getData() {
  return nullptr;
}

void wrapGetData(const void** ppData) {
  *ppData = getData();
}

int main() {
  const void *p;
  wrapGetData(&p);
}
```